# How can I use Linq to create an array of dictionaries from XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, arrays, dictionary

Given the following XML structure:

```
<courses>
  <course>
    <title>foo</title>
    <description>bar</description>
  </course>
  ...
</courses>
```

How could I create an array of dictionaries such that each dictionary contains all the element/value pairs within a course?

What I have right now generates an array whose elements contain a single key/value dictionary for each element/value pair in a course:

```
XElement x = XElement.Parse("...xml string...");
var foo = (from n in x.Elements() select n)
    .Elements().ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Value);
```

Produces:

```
[0] => {[course, foo]}
[1] => {[description, bar]}
```

What I'd like is this:

```
[0] => {[course, foo], [description, bar]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
x.Elements("course")
 .Select(c => c.Elements().ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Value))
 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Visual Studio complains that 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for ToDictionary().

Comment: The result is the same as the undesired structure illustrated in my question - an array of single-entry dictionaries.

Comment: I tried it, and  I got an array of double-entry dictionaries.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  I was misinterpreting how the VS debugger displayed the data structure.  Thank you!